# install not complete mongodb on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: database, mongodb, windows-7

when install mongo database on windows 7
is not complete instillation

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUGAp.png)

how to solve this problem

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!

Comment: Maybe report about this issue to MongoDB team.

Answer (score 26):

I too have the same issue while installing mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.3-signed.msi

Follow the below steps to resolve the problem

1. Run the installer with a double-click.
2. Click next.
3. Accept the License Agreement.
4. Select the Complete installation type and click Install
5. Uncheck the Install Compass option (by default this checked and Compass requires the Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5 or later)
6. With in a minute time installation will get complete and you can see the exe files under C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin

You can follow the url https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/install/ for installing Compass (The GUI for MongoDB) later.

Comment: Thanks very much i was also having same problem... This answer solved my problem.

Comment: Worked for me but I have .NET Framework version 4.8 and PowerShell version 5.1 installed so it is not exactly that problem.

Comment: How to uncheck option install Compass? in my master mongodb(ver 4.2.8), after choose complete setup type there is only service configuration that contain option to run service as network or local

Comment: @isnainibarochatun  - For this version ==> after step 4 above click "next" (The checkbox will be on the next (Sepereate ) screen - named: "Install MongoDB compass").